# What could be causing issues when putting my HTML code into an email, even though it works well when opened separately?

Tags: html, css

Here is my html code, and it works well, when I open it. When I put this html file into the email, something goes wrong.

Here is what I expect.

[image]

This is the HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="zh-Hant">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">

  <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#ffffff" style=" max-width: 600px; border-collapse: collapse; color: #333333;line-height: 1.4;border: 1px solid #dddddd;margin-top: 20px; font-family: -apple-system, Helvetica, Arial;">
      <tr bgcolor="#ffffff">
        <td align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="padding: 0px 34px;">
          <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="border-collapse: collapse;font-size: 16px;color: #333333;">
            <tr>
              <td>
                <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; margin-top: 22px;">
                  <div style="display: flex; align-items: center; flex-shrink: 0; padding: 8px 0px;">
                    <img
                      src="xxx.png"
                      alt="sign-in"
                      style="width: 68px; height: 68px; align-self: stretch;"
                    />
                    <div style="color: #212121; margin-left: 16px;">
                      This is the first title - <strong>Important message 1</strong>
                    </div>
                  </div> 
                  <div style="display: flex; align-self: stretch; align-items: center; flex-shrink: 0; padding: 8px 0px;">
                    <img
                      src="xxx.png"
                      alt="pop"
                      style="width: 68px; height: 68px; align-self: stretch;"
                    />
                    <div style="color: #212121; margin-left: 16px;">
                      This is the second title - <strong>Important message 2</strong>
                    </div>
                  </div>                                           
                  <div style="display: flex; align-self: stretch; align-items: center; flex-shrink: 0; padding: 8px 0px;">
                    <img
                      src="xxx.png"
                      alt="treasure"
                      style="width: 68px; height: 68px; align-self: stretch;"
                    />
                    <div style="color: #212121; margin-left: 16px;">
                      This is the third title - <strong>Important message 3</strong>
                    </div>
                  </div> 
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>                           
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr bgcolor="#ffffff">
        <td align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="padding: 0px 34px;">
                                  
          <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="border-collapse: collapse;font-size: 16px;color: #333333;">
            <tr>
              <td>
                <div align="left" style="font-size: 24px; padding: 2px 0px; margin-bottom: 19px; line-height: 32px; margin-top: 38px;">
                  Learn something
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td>
                <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: row; gap: 25px; ">
                  <a href="https://xxx" target="_blank" style="text-decoration: none; display: flex; flex-direction: column;">
                    <img
                      src="xxx.png"
                      alt="video1"
                      style="width: 160px; height: 90px;"
                    />
                    <div style="color: #212121; font-size: 14px; line-height: 20px; letter-spacing: 0.25px;">
                      Welcome to <span style="color: #3674FF; ">MY.TV</span>
                    </div>
                  </a>
                  <a href="https://xxx" target="_blank" style="text-decoration: none; display: flex; flex-direction: column;">
                    <img
                      src="xxx.png"
                      alt="video2"
                      style="width: 160px; height: 90px;"
                    />
                    <div style="color: #212121; font-size: 14px; line-height: 20px; letter-spacing: 0.25px;">
                      Thanks for visting our website <span style="color: #3674FF; ">MY.TV</span>
                    </div>
                  </a> 
                  <a href="https://xxx" target="_blank" style="text-decoration: none; display: flex; flex-direction: column;">
                    <img
                      src="xxx.png"
                      alt="video3"
                      style="width: 160px; height: 90px;"
                    />
                    <div style="color: #212121; font-size: 14px; line-height: 20px; letter-spacing: 0.25px;">
                      Enjoy the journey from <span style="color: #3674FF; ">MY.TV</span>
                    </div>
                  </a>                                        
                  
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

**After I put the HTML file into an email, send it to me. It becomes like this, sorry this is just a schematic diagram, the framework just looks like this.**

Is that something I can improve through the code?

[image]

Comment: email clients do barely support modern CSS3 and HTML5. The safest solution is to fall back to HTML4 and the inline-style that was used during that time. Flexbox or Grid are barely supported!

Comment: I always fall back to a table based layout and inline styles. Only use style tags with media queries for mobile clients. E-Mail clients don't take divs the way you expect. Check [Compain Monitor](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/) for compatibility between email clients as well.

Comment: This can also be a useful reference: https://www.caniemail.com/ I guess you are having problems with flex on some systems.

Comment: I convert all the code to the table based, and it works. Thanks.